# How do I backup and restore iPhones with ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

Okay so I want to know how do I backup and restore iPhone data using ubuntu cause I know I can't download and use iTunes and i know you can get like Linuxplay or something like that but is there something else that's works fine?

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/idevicebackup.1.html

Comment: But how do I use this?

Comment: There's two pretty good answers [right here.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170347/complete-iphone-backup-without-itunes) You'll likely either need to install a Virtual Machine to run Windows/macOS with Itunes, or try out the other option which is an unofficial iDevice backup. To use the idevicebackup, you can make a backup by running `idevicebackup backup /path/to/where/you/want/your/backups`

Comment: i don't know. i use dual boot with hackintosh sierra. its a terminal command so it should be something like: idevicebackup backup <path to where you want to save the "backup">. the other and best ubuntu itunes solution is a virtual machine with windows which is already answered http://askubuntu.com/questions/797038/how-to-manage-and-restore-a-modern-iphone-or-idevice-on-ubuntu-with-itunes

Comment: I wouldn't use idevicebackup, if you have to use apple proprietary crap you better stay with their official provided methods, by going unofficial you risk not bieng able to recover that backup or being corrupted or any kind of similar nightmare.